# Reference a node from Java DOM to JTextArea content

Tags: java, swing, dom, xpath

I have an XML document and execute two task:

> 1. Read it into JTextArea.
> 2. Parse it into DOM to retrieve node using XPath.

My question is **How to reference a node from DOM (I have retrieved) to content of JTextArea?**.

By the way, I found the answer to scroll JTextArea to the line matched to that node.

Comment: Also consider using a `ListSelectionListener` with a `JTable` or `JList`.

Answer (score 0):

1 you parse the XML in DOM

2 you regenerate your XML, node by node

3 for each node, you keep line position, and append a CRLF.

4 and keep line size

5 etc.